# rabbitmq TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm getting below error while joining the cluster

```
root@hostname02:~# rabbitmqctl join_cluster --longnames rabbit@hostname01
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@hostname02'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@hostname02
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@hostname02']

rabbit@hostname02:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on hostname02
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Node name (or hostname) mismatch: node "rabbit@hostname02" believes its node name is not "rabbit@hostname02" but something else.
    All nodes and CLI tools must refer to node "rabbit@hostname02" using the same name the node itself uses (see its logs to find out what it is)


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-7548-rabbit@hostname02'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: Uaa+OhOna5fm+J0oPGPAiw==

root@hostname02:~#
```

`.erlang.cookie` on both the servers are same.

I cannot see what I am missing here. Can someone help in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `--longnames` option. Erlang nodes (and thus, its distribution protocol) only need longnames if there is a dot in the host part.

Also, check the node name reported by RabbitMQ on startup, and verify that it matches `rabbit@hostname02`

Comment: @Panda and what about the startup report by RabbitMQ? (cookie hash and node name?)